# C# WPF does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace=local"

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2019

i've just facing error from C# WPF to load a local assembly Cs from the folder below. Also i've set my path for the assembly correctly, but i still facing error like this.

"the name 'aaa' does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:aaa'"

I've searched the web for similar errors and have made sure that I've followed all available suggestions, like:

1. Change my current build target platform to the other one ie x64 if currently x86.
2. Re-build my entire solution.
3. Change back to required target platform ie x86 and re-build my solution.

and everything still the same. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and using WPF C#
thank you before. i've attached my Screenshoot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yzgd.png).

Comment: How is your DesignerCanvas.cs?

Comment: everything is correct and facing no error, i'm using namespace DashboardDesigner{ class() }

Answer (score -1):

The namespace block declared in DesignerCanvas.cs must be exactly like you are calling it on XAML, like this:

```
namespace DashboardDesigner.DashboardDesigner.Properties {
    public class DesignerCanvas {
        ...
    }
}
```

Remember that your folder structure doesn't define directly your namespace path, although it is highly recommended that you keep your namespaces paths matching the folder structure so it is easy to locate yourself in your project.

Also, be sure to only use `{x:Static}` with something that is really declared as `static` or it is static by definition, like an `enum` item.